# Erro ao implementar o swagger

Tags: c#, asp-net-core, swagger

Estou tentando implementar o swagger na minha aplicação mas obtive os erro, ao subir a aplicação

[image: Erro Swagger]

Fiz seguindo a documentação da microsoft, mas, não obtive sucesso. Parece um erro muito genérico, portanto peço ajuda.
Aqui minha classe para configuração do swagger:

```
public static class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddSwaggerConfig(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c => 
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = "TestApi",
                    Description = "Primeira versão da API"
                });
            });
            return services;
        }

        public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerConfig(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger.json", "v1");
            });
            return app;
        }
    }
```

Minha Startup:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
...
            services.AddControllers();
            
            services.AddSwaggerConfig();
..
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
   
    app.UseSwaggerConfig();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });


}
```

}

Comment: O que acontece quando você tenta acessar https://localhost:5001/swagger/swagger.json pelo browser?

Comment: Erro HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: o que parece é que ele está procurando pelo swagger.json no caminho /swagger/swagger.json, mas no c.swaggerEndpoint você marcou apenas "swagger.json"

Comment: Se eu aumento um *swagger* no endpoint, ele aumenta um *swagger* no browser. Ou seja, `swagger/swagger.jon` no endpoint, no browser eu tenho `swagger/swagger/swagger.json`

Comment: da uma olhada no visual studio na janela de saida qual exception ele ta lançando, pode ser alguma coisa relacionado nos controllers e não na configuração